Counting the occurrence of a character based on whether there is a value in a different cell
I am trying to figure out how many games a team has played on the road already given their entire schedule. Using COUNT for the column (C) that contains "@" (that is the only value in the column if it's an away game, blank if at home) counts all occurrences. I only want the games that have actually been played. To do this, I'm thinking of referencing another column that has a value in it, say Goals For, GF (E). This column will have always have a value if the game has been played. I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I haven't had luck finding it online! Thank you for your help!

Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no question in your post. See How do I ask a good question and How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

This should match your need (table & column names to be adjusted):
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Col C]; "@"; Table1[Goals For];"<>")


Perfect, this allows me to take the total number of away games for the season and subtract the amount from what you suggested to get my answer, thanks! =COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!C3:C84) - COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C3:C84, "@", Sheet1!E3:E84,"")
